# Using a variable inside option name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gsap

I need to do this:

```
  let parallaxBp = 768;

  ScrollTrigger.matchMedia({
    "(min-width: " + parallaxBp + "px)": function() {
      // code
    }
  });
```

but doesn't work, it says

```
, expected
```

So I can't concatenate that string. How can do it?

Comment: Put square brackets around the string. See [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).

Comment: the concatenation is working fine. 

"(min-width: 768px)", but it needs to be encapsulated in square brackets to be used as variable.

["(min-width: " + parallaxBp + "px)"]: function(){}